# Create plugin for scorm editor

Tags: html, scorm

There are lots of content editors for SCORM.
We have specific educational java applet, and we'd like to create plugin for any scorm editor (that makes easy to embed it into scorm lessons). But in fact, I don't have much experience with scorm editors, so which scorm editor is better to focus on? Where I can find information about creating plugins api for scorm editors?
Does anybody have such experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most SCORM editors are closed source software and may not have external integration points. There are open source solutions, but they can be hit and miss as to having an API.

The short answer is there is not common integration point among these applications. Each integration would require a conversation with each companies development to determine if they allow integration.